# Tokenizer Class for handling .csv files in c++17

Tags: c++, beginner, c++17, lexical-analysis

I am a hobbyist computer programmer trying to learn modern C++ (in this case C++17). I thought it might be an interesting challenge to write a `tokenizer class` for breaking down microsoft (and other) .CSV files into tokens. My `token`s are simply a `std::variant<int, double, std::string>`, and I wrote an `enum class` to facilitate easy code reading. I have chosen to make functions camelCase, and variables snake_case.

I do have some questions:

- Is my constructor "kosher"? That is, I know that it can throw an exception.
- I also know that it could be rewritten as a bunch of overloads, would that be better?
- Is my dependence on overloading the << and >> operators along with specialized functions considered good style or should I choose one paradigm and force the user to adapt?
- Are there other stylistic or algorithmic problems throughout this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <fstream>
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

/*
123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 1234567890
*/
using std::cout;
using namespace std::string_literals;

using token = std::variant<int, double, std::string>;

enum class token_type : std::size_t  {
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    STRING
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{
    std::visit([&out](const auto& content) {out << content; }, tok);
    return out;
}

class tokenizer
{
public:
    tokenizer(const char* delim = ",;:|\t ", const char* escape = "\"\'",
        bool unquote = true, bool remove_blanks = false, bool convert = true) :
        delim_{ std::string(escape).append(delim) }, escape_{ escape },
        unquote_{ unquote }, remove_blanks_{ remove_blanks }, 
        convert_{ convert }  {};
    tokenizer& operator<<(std::string_view s);
    tokenizer& operator<<(const char* line);
    tokenizer& operator>>(token& tok);
    tokenizer& operator>>(std::optional<token>& otok);
    void operator>>(std::vector<token>& toks);
    std::optional<token> getNext();
    std::vector<token> getVector();
    void clear() { toks_.clear(); }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string_view s);
    void convertString(std::string s);
    std::deque<token> toks_;
    const std::string delim_{ };
    const std::string_view escape_{ };
    bool unquote_{ true };
    bool remove_blanks_{ false };
    bool convert_{ true };
};

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator<<(std::string_view s)
{
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        if (!remove_blanks_) toks_.emplace_back("");
        return *this;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> temp_vec = splitString(s);
    for (auto& value : temp_vec) {
        auto start = 0;
        auto count = value.length();
        if (remove_blanks_ && (count == 0 || (count == 2 && unquote_ &&
            escape_.find(value[0]) != escape_.npos))) {
            continue;
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            if (unquote_) toks_.emplace_back(value);  //  token_type::STRING
            else toks_.emplace_back(""s + *(escape_.cbegin()) + *(escape_.cbegin()));
            continue;
        }
        auto q_index = std::find(escape_.begin(), escape_.end(), value[0]);
        if (q_index != escape_.end() && value[0] == *q_index) {
            if (!unquote_) {
                toks_.emplace_back(value);  //  token_type::STRING
                continue;
            }
            ++start;
            count -= 2;
            std::string double_quote{ ""s + *q_index + *q_index };
            auto pos = value.find(double_quote, 1);  // "\"\""
            while (pos != std::string::npos && pos != value.length() - 2) {
                --count;
                value.erase(pos, 1);
                pos = value.find(double_quote, 1);  // "\"\""
            }
            value = value.substr(start, count);
        }

        if (convert_) convertString(value);
        else toks_.emplace_back(value);  //  token_type::STRING
    }
    return *this;
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator<<(const char* line)
{
    return operator<<(std::string_view(line));
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator>>(token& tok)
{
    tok = std::move(toks_.front());
    toks_.pop_front();
    return *this;
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator>>(std::optional<token>& otok)
{
    if (toks_.empty()) {
        otok = std::nullopt;
        return *this;
    }
    otok = std::move(toks_.front());
    toks_.pop_front();
    return *this;
}

void tokenizer::operator>>(std::vector<token>& toks)
{
    toks.reserve(toks.size()+toks_.size());
    while (!toks_.empty()) {
        toks.push_back(std::move(toks_.front()));
        toks_.pop_front();
    }
    toks_.clear();
}

std::optional<token> tokenizer::getNext()
{
    if (toks_.empty()) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    token ret(std::move(toks_.front()));
    toks_.pop_front();
    return ret;
}

std::vector<token> tokenizer::getVector()
{
    std::vector<token> ret;
    ret.reserve(toks_.size());
    while (!toks_.empty()) {
        ret.push_back(toks_.front());
        toks_.pop_front();
    }
    toks_.clear();
    return ret;
}

std::vector<std::string> tokenizer::splitString(std::string_view s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    auto start = s.begin();
    while (*start == ' ') ++start;
    auto pos = std::find_first_of(start, s.end(), delim_.cbegin(),
        delim_.cend());
    while (pos != s.end()) {
        auto q_index = std::find(escape_.begin(), escape_.end(), *pos);
        if (q_index != escape_.end()) {
            pos = std::find(pos + 1, s.end(), *q_index);
            if ((pos + 1) != s.end() && *(pos + 1) == *q_index) {
                ++pos;
                continue;
            }
            pos = std::find_first_of(pos + 1, s.end(), delim_.cbegin(),
                delim_.cend());
        }
        ret.emplace_back(s, start - s.begin(), pos - start);
        if (pos == s.end()) {
            start = pos;
            break;
        }
        start = pos + 1;
        while (*start == ' ') ++start;
        pos = std::find_first_of(start, s.end(), delim_.begin(),
            delim_.end());
    }
    if (start != s.end()) ret.emplace_back(s, start - s.begin(),
        s.end() - start);
    return ret;
}

void tokenizer::convertString(std::string s)
{
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        toks_.emplace_back(s);
        return;
    }
    std::uint8_t offset = 0;
    if (s[0] == '-' || s[0] == '+') ++offset;
    auto iter = std::find_if(s.begin()+offset, s.end(),
        [](unsigned char c) noexcept -> bool {
            return !(isdigit(c) || c == '.');
        });
    if (iter != s.end()) {
        toks_.emplace_back(s);  // , token_type::STRING
        return;
    }
    iter = std::find_if(s.begin() + offset, s.end(), [](unsigned char c)
        {
            return c == '.';
        });
    std::stringstream iss{ s };
    if (iter != s.end()) {
        double dvalue;
        iss >> dvalue;
        toks_.emplace_back(dvalue);  // , token_type::DOUBLE
        return;
    }
    int ivalue;
    iss >> ivalue;
    toks_.emplace_back(ivalue);  // , token_type::INT
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto typer = [](std::size_t index) -> const char*
    {
        switch (static_cast<token_type>(index)) {
        case token_type::STRING:
            return "string";
        case token_type::DOUBLE:
            return "double";
        case token_type::INT:
        default:
            return "int";
        }
    };
    tokenizer token_maker (",", "\""); // , true, false, true
    token_maker << "";
    token_maker << "\"help, this!\",32";
    token_maker << "gasoline" << "";
    std::vector<token> tokens{ token_maker.getVector() };
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    std::string test_string;
    std::istringstream iss("1,\"\"\"2,3\"\", a\",4,-1.1,,\"\", 5,\"asdf\"");
    std::getline(iss, test_string);
    cout << test_string << " unquote, !remove_blanks, convert\n";
    tokens.clear();
    token_maker << test_string >> tokens;
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " <<
        typer(t.index()) << "\n"; //  t.index()
    cout << "\n";
    cout << test_string << " !unquote, !remove_blanks, convert\n";
    std::optional<token> next_tok;
    tokenizer token_maker2(",", "\"", false);
    token_maker2 << test_string;
    token_maker2 >> next_tok;
    while (next_tok) {
        cout << *next_tok << " : " << typer(next_tok->index()) << "\n";
        token_maker2 >> next_tok;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << test_string << " !unquote, remove_blanks, convert\n";
    tokenizer token_maker3(",", "\"", false, true);
    token_maker3 << test_string;
    while (auto next_tok = token_maker3.getNext()) cout << *next_tok << " : " <<
        typer(next_tok->index()) << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << test_string << " !unquote, remove_blanks, !convert\n";
    tokenizer token_maker4(",", "\"", false, true, false);
    tokens.clear();
    token_maker4 << test_string >>tokens;
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << test_string << " unquote, remove_blanks, convert\n";
    tokenizer token_maker5(",", "\"", true, true, true);
    tokens.clear();
    token_maker5 << test_string >> tokens;
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
    cout << "\nBreaking down typical .csv file: delimited by ,using \"";
    cout << " as escape characters, and unquote, !remove_blanks,";
    cout << "converting to type\n\n";
    std::vector<token> headings;
    headings.reserve(15);
    std::ifstream test_data("ExportedGridData.csv");
    std::getline(test_data, test_string);
    token_maker << test_string >> headings;
    int i=0, category_column=-1;
    for (auto t : headings) {
        std::string s = *std::get_if<std::string>(&t);
        if (s.find("Categories", 0)!=s.npos) category_column = i;
        ++i;
    }
    const auto last_column = headings.size() - 1;
    if (last_column != category_column) {
        headings.erase(headings.begin() + category_column);
        headings.emplace_back("Categories"s);
    }
    for (auto t : headings) cout << t << " ";
    cout << "\n";
    while (std::getline(test_data, test_string)) {
        token_maker << test_string;
        std::vector<token> data;
        token_maker >> data;
        token_maker << std::get<std::string>(data.at(category_column)) >> data;
        data.erase(data.begin()+category_column);
        std::sort(data.begin() + last_column, data.end(), 
            [](const token & a, const token & b) -> bool {
                return a < b;
            });
        for (auto s : data) cout << s << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 : string
help, this! : string
32 : int
gasoline : string
 : string

1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" unquote, !remove_blanks, convert
1 : int
"2,3", a : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
 : string
 : string
5 : int
asdf : string

1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !unquote, !remove_blanks, convert
1 : int
"""2,3"", a" : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
"" : string
"" : string
5 : int
"asdf" : string

1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !unquote, remove_blanks, convert
1 : int
"""2,3"", a" : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
"" : string
5 : int
"asdf" : string

1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !unquote, remove_blanks, !convert
1 : string
"""2,3"", a" : string
4 : string
-1.1 : string
"" : string
5 : string
"asdf" : string

1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" unquote, remove_blanks, convert
1 : int
"2,3", a : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
5 : int
asdf : string

Breaking down typical .csv file: delimited by ,using " as escape characters, and unquote, !remove_blanks,converting to type

Order Question Title ID/Rev Type Status difficulty Weight Avg Answer Time  Group Last Editor Categories
1 Free Radical 66526 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0.623596 1 1:16  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
2 Phosphatitic acid 70264 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.314286 1 1:44  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
3 Copy of Epimers 2 70231 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.0714286 1 3:24  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
4 'Epimers 2' 70230 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.457143 1 2:45  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
5 "Anabolism" 65576 / 4 MChoice TRUE 0.62605 1 1:05  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) Fed/Fast L01 - Introductory
6 dilution of hydroxide 70284 / 2 Fill in the Blank TRUE 0.185714 1 2:58  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing) L01 - Introductory Water/pH/pKa
7 What Changes 68853 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0.414286 1 1:52  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Protein Structure-Function
8 Secondary Structure 68854 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.357143 1 1:33  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Protein Structure-Function
9 Kinases 3358 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0 1 0  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry B05 Biochemistry/Biotechnology B05.01 chemistry of biomacromolecules (proteins Protein Structure-Function and DNA) carbohydrates lipids
10 Competitive FITB 21116 / 4 Fill in the Blank TRUE 0.185714 1 5:53 NC Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing) Enzyme Regulation L01 - Introductory
```

Notice the double space after the time, indicating not removing a column when blank.

Responses will be appreciated.

Edit: improved `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)`

Edit:
ExportedGridData.csv:

```
Order,Question Title,ID/Rev,Type,Status,difficulty,Weight,Avg Answer Time ,Group,Last Editor,Categories
1,Free Radical,66526 / 2,MChoice,TRUE,0.623595506,1,1:16,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), B01 Biochemistry, Parts"
2,Phosphatitic acid,70264 / 1,MChoice,TRUE,0.314285714,1,1:44,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), B01 Biochemistry, Parts"
3,Copy of Epimers 2,70231 / 1,MChoice,TRUE,0.071428571,1,3:24,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), B01 Biochemistry, Parts"
4,'Epimers 2',70230 / 1,MChoice,TRUE,0.457142857,1,2:45,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), B01 Biochemistry, Parts"
5,"""Anabolism""",65576 / 4,MChoice,TRUE,0.62605042,1,1:05,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), Fed/Fast, B01 Biochemistry"
6,dilution of hydroxide,70284 / 2,Fill in the Blank,TRUE,0.185714286,1,2:58,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing), B01 Biochemistry, Water/pH/pKa"
7,What Changes,68853 / 2,MChoice,TRUE,0.414285714,1,1:52,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), Protein Structure-Function, B01 Biochemistry"
8,Secondary Structure,68854 / 1,MChoice,TRUE,0.357142857,1,1:33,,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding), Protein Structure-Function, B01 Biochemistry"
9,Kinases,3358 / 2,MChoice,TRUE,0,1,-,,"Harrison, D"," B05 Biochemistry/Biotechnology, B05.01 chemistry of biomacromolecules (proteins, lipids, carbohydrates, and DNA), Protein Structure-Function, B01 Biochemistry"
10,Competitive FITB,21116 / 4,Fill in the Blank,TRUE,0.185714286,1,5:53,NC,"Harrison, D"," L01 - Introductory, BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing), Enzyme Regulation,B01 Biochemistry"
```

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for providing the test program.  That always makes code easier to review.  Unfortunately, when I tried it, I found a null pointer dereference here:

> ```
>     std::string s = *std::get_if<std::string>(&t);
> ```

I had to replace with

```
    auto p = std::get_if<std::string>(&t);
    if (!p) { continue; }
    std::string s = *p;
```

The test program really looks like it could benefit from being divided into individual tests within a unit-test framework (and the tests could become self-checking, rather than relying on a human to read the output).  In fact, I normally recommend a test-first approach for code like this.

I'd recommend including the `ExportedGridData.csv` as a string stream, rather than relying on an external resource (which we reviewers don't have!).  If you do keep it external, then at least check (e.g. `if (test_data)` that we've successfully read from it before assuming that `test_string` is valid.

In fact, this lack of checking of streaming is prevalent throughout the code - e.g. in `convertString()`.

---

The `token_type` enum doesn't buy us much.  It's only used in `main()` (so could be reduced in scope), and there only within a single `switch`.  It might be simpler to just use the numeric values there, with comments.  The one advantage to having it close to `token` definition is that we can see that it matches.

Given that it's intended to be used to convert from `std::size_t` values, perhaps it ought to be plain `enum` rather than `enum class`?

---

The streaming out operator could use the return value from `std::visit()` as its own return value.  There's a slight wrinkle in that lambda expressions normally return values rather than references; to return a reference we need to either specify the return type explicitly:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{
    return std::visit([&out](const auto& content) -> std::ostream& { return out << content; }, tok);
}
```

or use a `std::reference_wrapper` (from `<functional>`):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{
    return std::visit([&out](const auto& content) { return std::ref(out << content); }, tok);
}
```

It's probably better to name the lambda, so it's more readable and a sane line length:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{
    auto const print = [&out](const auto& content) -> std::ostream&
                       { return out << content; };
    return std::visit(print, tok);
}
```

---

Moving on to `tokenizer`, its constructor ought to be `explicit`, since it can be invoked with a single argument.  I'm not a fan of multiple `bool` arguments like that, as it's hard to see at the call site what each one means.

This overload of the `<<` operator has no benefit, since `std::string_view` has a converting constructor from `const char*`:

```
tokenizer& tokenizer::operator<<(const char* line)
{
    return operator<<(std::string_view(line));
}
```

Just remove it and C-style strings work fine.

I think it's clearer to write `(s.empty())` than `if (s.length() == 0)`.

The actual tokenization is very hard to follow, particularly with the different options affecting its behaviour.  I expected to see a simple state machine for this parsing.  It might be simpler to deal with `remove_blanks` and `strip_quotes` (and possibly also `convert`) when streaming out rather than in.

A different approach to determining the type would be to attempt to convert to integer, else to float and finally keep as a string, and let the conversions tell us which was successful (e.g. using `std::stoi()` and `std::stod()`, or `std::stringstream`'s input operators).

---

When writing to a vector, there's no need for a loop to build the vector an element at a time.  `std::deque` is a standard container, so we can create the vector directly from its start and end iterators:

```
void tokenizer::operator>>(std::vector<token>& out)
{
    out.insert(out.end(), toks_.begin(), toks_.end());
    toks_.clear();
}

std::vector<token> tokenizer::getVector()
{
    std::vector<token> ret{toks_.begin(), toks_.end()};
    toks_.clear();
    return ret;
}
```

We might consider `std::move()` algorithm instead, to reduce string copying.

---

In the test program, there's an obvious candidate for a raw string:

> ```
> std::istringstream iss("1,\"\"\"2,3\"\", a\",4,-1.1,,\"\", 5,\"asdf\"");
> ```

I think this is much easier to read (admittedly, the Stack Exchange syntax highlighter doesn't yet handle it properly, but good editors do):

```
std::istringstream iss(R"***(1,"""2,3"", a",4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf")***");
```

---

There's no need for `using std::cout;` at global scope.  If you really feel it's worthwhile, this can be within `main()`.

We're quite right to import the whole `std::string_literals` namespace - that's one of the few namespaces designed to be used like that.

Comment: Thank you for the review! How does one include a file like `ExportedGridData.csv`? I was trying to demonstrate a "practical example of how the `tokenizer` class might be used. I never saw a null pointer dereference error. Interestingly, your ostream code results in a runtime error in VS 2019 C++ "The thread 0x5950 has exited with code 0 (0x0)." I'm thinking that we are seeing differences in how different compilers are implemented.... I am not qualified to say which one conforms to the c++17 standard.

Comment: You should be able to include the file the same way that you included the other sample code, using a string-stream (you might want to use raw strings to compose it, so it's less tedious).  You probably don't see the null pointer because you have a `ExportedGridData.csv` file to read.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through @Toby_Speight's Review, I adopted a number of changes to (I hope) improve the code.

First, I separated the `Tokenizer` class into its own .hpp file so that it can now be readily used by a number of different projects.

Second, I changed the constructor to now only allow for the delimiters and the escape characters. The `Tokenizer` class uses defaults for handling of weather or not to remove **escape characters** (and turn double escape characters into a single escape character), remove **empty tokens**, convert from **strings** to **ints** or **doubles**, and to **trim white spaces** from the beginning and end of tokens. I decided that needing a new tokenizer for each of these was "safe", but highly burdensome. To give the user control over these defaults, I included `removeQuotes`, `removeBlanks`, `typeConvertion`, and `trimWhiteSpace` "setter" functions. Since, the `Tokenizer` class does all of its tokenizing during the input phase (`operator<<()`) I decided to clear any existing tokens when these "setters" were used. I can think of no use case where you would want to use to different switches for different input data without using the tokens in between input strings.

Third, I decided that trimming white spaces should be a user option and not hard wired `trimWhiteSpace`.

Fourth, I made some private functions to clean up redundancy in the code and make the main code easier to read. These new functions include `empty_string`, `parse`, and `emplace_string`. The function `parse` also represents my attempt to make use of the new c++17 function `from_chars` and clean up some of its clunky interface.

The `tokenizer.hpp` code is shown below:

```
// Tokenizer.hpp

#ifndef TOKENIZER_HPP
#define TOKENIZER_HPP

#include <algorithm>
#include <charconv>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_literals;

using token = std::variant<int, double, std::string>;

enum class token_type : std::size_t {
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    STRING
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const token& tok)
{

    std::visit([&out](auto&& content) {out << content; }, tok);
    return out;
}

using svciter = std::string_view::const_iterator;

class tokenizer
{
public:
    explicit tokenizer(const char* delim = ",;:|\t ",
        const char* escape = "\"\'") :
        delim_{ std::string(escape).append(delim) }, escape_{ escape } {}
    tokenizer& operator<<(std::string_view s);
    tokenizer& operator>>(token& tok);
    tokenizer& operator>>(std::optional<token>& otok);
    void operator>>(std::vector<token>& toks);
    std::optional<token> getNext();
    std::vector<token> getVector();
    void removeQuotes(bool remove_quotes);
    void removeBlanks(bool remove_blanks);
    void typeConvertion(bool convert);
    void trimWhiteSpace(bool trim);
    void clear() { toks_.clear(); }

private:
    std::vector<std::string_view> splitString(std::string_view s);
    void convertString(std::string_view s);
    std::string empty_string();
    template <class T>
    std::optional<T> parse(std::string_view s);
    void emplace_string(std::string_view s);
    std::deque<token> toks_;
    const std::string delim_{ };
    const std::string_view escape_{ };
    bool remove_quotes_{ true };
    bool remove_blanks_{ false };
    bool type_convert_{ true };
    bool trim_{ true };
};

std::string tokenizer::empty_string()
{
    if (remove_quotes_ || escape_.length() == 0) return "";
    return ""s + *(escape_.cbegin()) + *(escape_.cbegin());
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator<<(std::string_view s)
{
    if (s.empty()) {
        if (!remove_blanks_) toks_.emplace_back(empty_string());
        return *this;
    }
    std::vector<std::string_view> temp_vec = splitString(s);
    for (auto& value : temp_vec) {
        auto count = value.length();
        if (remove_blanks_ && (count == 0 || (count == 2 && remove_quotes_ &&
            escape_.find(value[0]) != escape_.npos))) {
            continue;
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            toks_.emplace_back(empty_string());
            continue;
        }
        auto q_index = std::find(escape_.begin(), escape_.end(), value[0]);
        std::string temp;
        if (q_index != escape_.end() && value[0] == *q_index) {
            if (!remove_quotes_) {
                std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
                toks_.push_back(temp);   // token_type::STRING
                continue;
            }
            std::copy(value.begin() + 1, value.end() - 1, std::back_inserter(temp));
            const std::string double_quote{ ""s + *q_index + *q_index };
            for (auto pos = temp.find(double_quote, 0);
                pos != std::string::npos; pos = temp.find(double_quote, 0)) {
                temp.erase(pos, 1);
            }
            value = temp;
        }
        if (type_convert_) convertString(value);
        else {
            std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
            toks_.push_back(temp);  //;    token_type::STRING
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator>>(token& tok)
{
    tok = std::move(toks_.front());
    toks_.pop_front();
    return *this;
}

tokenizer& tokenizer::operator>>(std::optional<token>& otok)
{
    if (toks_.empty()) {
        otok = std::nullopt;
        return *this;
    }
    otok = std::move(toks_.front());
    toks_.pop_front();
    return *this;
}

void tokenizer::operator>>(std::vector<token>& out)
{
    out.reserve(out.size() + toks_.size());
    out.insert(out.end(), toks_.begin(), toks_.end());
    toks_.clear();
}

std::optional<token> tokenizer::getNext()
{
    if (toks_.empty()) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    token ret(std::move(toks_.front()));
    toks_.pop_front();
    return ret;
}

std::vector<token> tokenizer::getVector()
{
    std::vector<token> ret;
    if (toks_.empty()) return ret;
    ret.reserve(toks_.size());
    std::move(toks_.begin(), toks_.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    toks_.clear();
    return ret;
}

void tokenizer::removeQuotes(bool remove_quotes)
{
    remove_quotes_ = remove_quotes;
    toks_.clear();
}

void tokenizer::removeBlanks(bool remove_blanks)
{
    remove_blanks_ = remove_blanks;
    toks_.clear();
}

void tokenizer::typeConvertion(bool convert)
{
    type_convert_ = convert;
    toks_.clear();
}

void tokenizer::trimWhiteSpace(bool trim)
{
    trim_ = trim;
    toks_.clear();
}

std::vector<std::string_view> tokenizer::splitString(std::string_view s)
{
    auto select_space = [&](char c) -> bool {
        if (!isspace(c)) return false;
        return delim_.find(c) == delim_.npos;
    };
    std::vector<std::string_view> ret;
    auto start = s.begin();
    if (trim_) while (select_space(*start)) ++start;
    auto pos_iter = std::find_first_of(start, s.end(), delim_.cbegin(),
        delim_.cend());
    while (pos_iter != s.end()) {
        auto q_index = std::find(escape_.begin(), escape_.end(), *pos_iter);
        if (q_index != escape_.end()) {
            pos_iter = std::find(pos_iter + 1, s.end(), *q_index);
            if ((pos_iter + 1) != s.end() && *(pos_iter + 1) == *q_index) {
                ++pos_iter;
                continue;
            }
            pos_iter = std::find_first_of(pos_iter + 1, s.end(),
                delim_.cbegin(), delim_.cend());
        }
        auto address = &s.at(start - s.begin());
        auto length = pos_iter - start;
        if (trim_) while (select_space(*(address + length - 1))) --length;
        ret.emplace_back(address, length);
        if (pos_iter == s.end()) return ret;
        if (pos_iter + 1 == s.end()) {
            ret.emplace_back("");
            return ret;
        }
        start = pos_iter + 1;
        if (trim_) while (select_space(*start)) ++start;
        pos_iter = std::find_first_of(start, s.end(), delim_.begin(),
            delim_.end());
    }
    auto address = &s.at(start - s.begin());
    auto length = s.end() - start;
    if (trim_) while (select_space(*(address + length - 1))) --length;
    ret.emplace_back(address, length);
    return ret;
}

template <typename T>
std::optional<T> tokenizer::parse(std::string_view s)
{
    T value;
    auto res = std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), value);
    if (res.ec != std::errc{}) return std::nullopt;
    return value;
}

void tokenizer::emplace_string(std::string_view s)
{
    std::string temp;
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
    toks_.emplace_back(temp);
}

void tokenizer::convertString(std::string_view s)
{
    if (s.empty()) {
        toks_.emplace_back("");
        return;
    }
    std::uint8_t offset = 0;
    if (s[0] == '-' || s[0] == '+') ++offset;
    auto iter = std::find_if(s.begin() + offset, s.end(),
        [](unsigned char c) noexcept -> bool {
            return !(isdigit(c) || c == '.');
        });
    if (iter != s.end() || s.begin() + offset == s.end()) {
        emplace_string(s);
        return;
    }
    if (s[0] == '+') {              // from_chars can't handle '+ddd'
        s = std::string_view(&s.at(1), s.size() - 1);
    }
    iter = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '.');
    if (iter != s.end()) {
        if (auto dvalue = parse<double>(s)) toks_.push_back(dvalue.value());
        else emplace_string(s);
        return;
    }
    if (auto ivalue = parse<int>(s)) toks_.push_back(ivalue.value());
    else emplace_string(s);
    return;
}

#endif // !TOKENIZER_HPP
```

As far as testing is concerned, I have included a `assert` statements to test that the output is as expected for eight different tests that demonstrate each of the approaches to get data into and out of the `tokenizer` and look at the effects of changing the "switches." I then show how the `tokenizer` class might be used in an application that takes apart a typical .csv file (see above).

This is the main.cpp code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include "tokenizer.hpp"

using std::cout;
using namespace std::string_literals;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto typer = [](std::size_t index) -> const char*
    {
        switch (static_cast<token_type>(index)) {
        case token_type::STRING:
            return "string";
        case token_type::DOUBLE:
            return "double";
        case token_type::INT:
        default:
            return "int";
        }
    };
    tokenizer token_maker (",", "\""); // , true, false, true
    token_maker << "";
    token_maker << R"("""help, this!""" ,+32 )";
    token_maker << R"("gasoline",.,.0,)"; 
    std::vector<token> test_tokens{ "",
        R"("help, this!")",32,"gasoline",".",0.,"" };
    std::vector<token> tokens{ token_maker.getVector() };
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
    assert(test_tokens.size() == tokens.size() && 
        std::equal(test_tokens.begin(), test_tokens.end(), tokens.begin())
        && "tokens are unexpected\n");
    cout << "PASSED zeroth test\n\n";
    std::string test_string;
    std::istringstream iss(R"*^*(1, """2,3"", a",   4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf")*^*");
    std::getline(iss, test_string);
    cout << test_string << " remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim\n";
    test_tokens = std::vector<token>{ 1, R"("2,3", a)", 4, -1.1, "", "", 5, 
        "asdf" };
    tokens.clear();
    token_maker << test_string >> tokens;
    assert(test_tokens.size() == tokens.size() && 
        std::equal(test_tokens.begin(), test_tokens.end(), tokens.begin()) &&
        "tokens are unexpected in first test\n");
    for (auto t : tokens) cout << t << " : " <<
        typer(t.index()) << "\n"; //  t.index()
    cout << "PASSED first test\n\n";
    token_maker.removeQuotes(false);
    cout << test_string << " !remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim\n";
    token_maker << test_string;
    std::optional<token> next_tok;
    test_tokens = std::vector<token>{ 1, R"("""2,3"", a")", 4, -1.1, "\"\"", 
        "\"\"", 5, "\"asdf\"" };
    auto iter_test = test_tokens.begin();
    token_maker >> next_tok;
    while (next_tok) {
        assert(iter_test != test_tokens.end() && 
            *next_tok == *iter_test++ && "unexpected tokens in second test");
        cout << *next_tok << " : " << typer(next_tok->index()) << "\n";
        token_maker >> next_tok;
    }
    cout << "PASSED second test\n\n";
    token_maker.removeBlanks(true);
    cout << test_string << " !remove_quotes, remove_blanks, convert, trim\n";
    test_tokens.erase(test_tokens.begin()+4);
    token_maker << test_string;
    iter_test = test_tokens.begin();
    while (auto next_tok = token_maker.getNext()) {
        assert(iter_test != test_tokens.end() &&
            *next_tok == *iter_test++ && "unexpected tokens in third test");
        cout << *next_tok << " : " <<
            typer(next_tok->index()) << "\n";
    }
    cout << "PASSED third test\n\n";
    token_maker.typeConvertion(false);
    token_maker.trimWhiteSpace(false);
    cout << test_string << " !remove_quotes, remove_blanks, !convert, !trim\n";
    tokens.clear();
    token_maker << test_string >>tokens;
    for (auto t : tokens) {
        cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
        assert(static_cast<token_type>(t.index()) == token_type::STRING &&
        "tokens are unexpected in fourth test\n");
    }
    cout << "PASSED fourth test\n\n";
    token_maker.removeQuotes(true);
    token_maker.typeConvertion(true);
    token_maker.trimWhiteSpace(true);
    cout << test_string << " remove_quotes, remove_blanks, convert, trim\n";
    tokens.clear();
    test_tokens = std::vector<token>{ 1, R"("2,3", a)", 4, -1.1,  5, "asdf" };
    iter_test = test_tokens.begin();
    token_maker << test_string >> tokens;
    for (auto t : tokens) {
        assert(iter_test != test_tokens.end() && 
            t == *iter_test++ && "unexpected tokens in fifth test");
        cout << t << " : " << typer(t.index()) << "\n";
    }
    cout << "PASSED fifth test\n\n";
    cout << "space delimited 'this is a + text now  ' ";
    cout << " remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim\n";
    tokenizer token_maker2{ " ","" };
    token_maker2 << "this is a +  text now  ";
    test_tokens = 
        std::vector<token>{ "this","is","a","+","","text","now","","" };
    iter_test = test_tokens.begin();
    while (auto next_tok = token_maker2.getNext()) {
        cout << '\"' << *next_tok << '\"' << "\n";
        assert(iter_test != test_tokens.end() && *next_tok == *iter_test++
            && "unexpected tokens in fifth test");
    }
    cout << "PASSED sixth test\n\n";
    token_maker.removeBlanks(false);
    cout << "Breaking down typical .csv file: delimited by , using \"";
    cout << " as escape characters, and removeQuotes = true, ";
    cout << "removeBlanks = false, typeConvertion = true\n\n";
    std::vector<token> headings;
    headings.reserve(15);
    std::ifstream test_data("ExportedGridData.csv");
    if (!test_data.is_open()) std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    std::getline(test_data, test_string);
    token_maker << test_string >> headings;
    int i=0, category_column=-1;
    for (auto t : headings) {
        std::string s = *std::get_if<std::string>(&t);
        if (s.find("Categories", 0)!=s.npos) category_column = i;
        ++i;
    }
    const auto last_column = headings.size() - 1;
    if (last_column != category_column) {
        headings.erase(headings.begin() + category_column);
        headings.emplace_back("Categories"s);
    }
    for (auto t : headings) cout << t << " ";
    cout << "\n";
    while (std::getline(test_data, test_string)) {
        token_maker << test_string;
        std::vector<token> data;
        token_maker >> data;
        token_maker << std::get<std::string>(data.at(category_column)) >> data;
        data.erase(data.begin()+category_column);
        std::sort(data.begin() + last_column, data.end(), 
            [](const token & a, const token & b) -> bool {
                return a < b;
            });
        for (auto s : data) cout << s << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
 : string
"help, this!" : string
32 : int
gasoline : string
. : string
0 : double
 : string
PASSED zeroth test

1, """2,3"", a",        4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim
1 : int
"2,3", a : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
 : string
 : string
5 : int
asdf : string
PASSED first test

1, """2,3"", a",        4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim
1 : int
"""2,3"", a" : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
"" : string
"" : string
5 : int
"asdf" : string
PASSED second test

1, """2,3"", a",        4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !remove_quotes, remove_blanks, convert, trim
1 : int
"""2,3"", a" : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
"" : string
5 : int
"asdf" : string
PASSED third test

1, """2,3"", a",        4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" !remove_quotes, remove_blanks, !convert, !trim
1 : string
 """2,3"", a" : string
        4 : string
-1.1 : string
"" : string
 5 : string
"asdf" : string
PASSED fourth test

1, """2,3"", a",        4,-1.1,,"", 5,"asdf" remove_quotes, remove_blanks, convert, trim
1 : int
"2,3", a : string
4 : int
-1.1 : double
5 : int
asdf : string
PASSED fifth test

space delimited 'this is a + text now  '  remove_quotes, !remove_blanks, convert, trim
"this"
"is"
"a"
"+"
""
"text"
"now"
""
""
PASSED sixth test

Breaking down typical .csv file: delimited by , using " as escape characters, and removeQuotes = true, removeBlanks = false, typeConvertion = true

Order Question Title ID/Rev Type Status difficulty Weight Avg Answer Time Group Last Editor Categories
1 Free Radical 66526 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0.623596 1 1:16  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
2 Phosphatitic acid 70264 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.314286 1 1:44  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
3 Copy of Epimers 2 70231 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.0714286 1 3:24  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
4 'Epimers 2' 70230 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.457143 1 2:45  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Parts
5 "Anabolism" 65576 / 4 MChoice TRUE 0.62605 1 1:05  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) Fed/Fast L01 - Introductory
6 dilution of hydroxide 70284 / 2 Fill in the Blank TRUE 0.185714 1 2:58  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing) L01 - Introductory Water/pH/pKa
7 What Changes 68853 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0.414286 1 1:52  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Protein Structure-Function
8 Secondary Structure 68854 / 1 MChoice TRUE 0.357143 1 1:33  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT01 - Recall (remembering and understanding) L01 - Introductory Protein Structure-Function
9 Kinases 3358 / 2 MChoice TRUE 0 1 -  Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry B05 Biochemistry/Biotechnology B05.01 chemistry of biomacromolecules (proteins Protein Structure-Function and DNA) carbohydrates lipids
10 Competitive FITB 21116 / 4 Fill in the Blank TRUE 0.185714 1 5:53 NC Harrison, D B01 Biochemistry BT02 - Interpretation (applying and analyzing) Enzyme Regulation L01 - Introductory
```

I hope this helps. Additional comments welcome.